# Storing disks of VM Instance

Tags: cloud, cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, cloud-computing

I recently began to use google cloud computing and used its VM instance of ubuntu to do some computation . Now I want to store the disk data of the VM Instance directly to the cloud storage so that I can delete the VM Instance as it charges per hour . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Are you sure it charges when it is turned off?

Comment: I think so . Because somewhere I read that we should delete the instance once work is completed because it charges. Moreover instance itself means a Instance having all the resources . Thus blocking the resources should charge anyway ? Isn't it ?

Comment: I’m not aware of any cloud provider that charges for a powered off VM. Google is no exception. You only pay for the storage the VM is using. Which is what you are already asking to do. I’m not real familiar with google. But if you want to save money on the storage cost then I believe you would take a snapshot and then delete the instance and storage. The snapshot can be restored to disk.

Comment: Yes you are right , I googled it . Thanks !!